# launch a xcodeproj from terminal

Tags: iphone, xcode

I trying to build and compile my `xcodeproj` in command line and it is working now.

So it is also possible to launch the `xcodeproject` from terminal instead from the Xcode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to run an app from the command line, use

```
open /path/to/appname.app
```

"Build and Go" is really just equivalent to

```
xcodebuild [parameters] && open /path/to/appname.app
```

Answer (score 7):

To run an Xcode project from terminal:

`open *.xcodeproj`

It may also be helpful to create an alias:

```
alias xcode="open *.xcodeproj"
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you asking for the command to build from the command-line?

It's just:

```
xcodebuild
```

There are lots of options available to pick non-default options:

```
Usage: xcodebuild [-project <projectname>] [-activetarget] [-alltargets] [-target <targetname>]... [-parallelizeTargets] [-activeconfiguration] [-configuration <configurationname>] [-sdk <sdkfullpath>|<sdkname>] [<buildsetting>=<value>]... [<buildaction>]...
   xcodebuild [-version [-sdk <sdkfullpath>|<sdkname>]]
   xcodebuild [-showsdks]
   xcodebuild [-find <binary>] [-sdk <sdkfullpath>|<sdkname>]
   xcodebuild [-list]
```

Answer (score 1):

xcodebuild -configuration Debug; open /path/to/build/Debug/your.app

BTW You can open any LaunchServices-findable app with a given document just by executing open -a  without a path or extension, e.g. open -a Xcode myProject.xcodeproj

Answer (score 0):

In terminal, in your project directory, just run:

```
xed .
```

**Bonus:** `xed` will correctly choose the `.xcworkspace` if one is available.