# How can I self-sign in Xcode for iPhone?

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

How can I self-sign an iPhone application using Xcode? I have done the following:

1. Created a cert following [these instructions](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW1)
2. Modified my `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist` to include the two keys

   <key>PROVISIONING_PROFILE_ALLOWED</key>
   <string>NO</string>
   <key>PROVISIONING_PROFILE_REQUIRED</key>
   <string>NO</string>
3. I have changed the info.plist associated with the project to say

<key>SignerIdentity</key>
<string>Apple iPhone OS Application Signing</string>

4. I have changed the project properties to refer to the signing authority with the name iPhone Developer, which is the name of my certificate.

The error is currently `a valid provisioning profile matching the applications identifier... cannot be found`.

**Note:** I am pretty sure that this can be done without a $99 cert from Apple. Also, I am not trying to build for the simulator but rather for the iPhone/iPod Touch itself.

Any insight would be appreciated.

[Perhaps Relevant link](http://www.vinodlive.com/2009/01/16/how-to-deploy-an-iphone-application-without-an-idp-membership/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#Developing_without_Provisioning_Profile? The link you've provided only works for SDK 2.x.

Comment: I haven't tried that whatsoever. +1 for now, best answer when I get around to trying it. Though I think I'm constrained to actually buying a cert to deploy to non-jailbroken phones. And THANKS yet again, KennyTM.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because you do not have the proper provisioning profile through the developer site of Apple, which follows from paying the $99 yearly.  It may somehow work on a jail broken device which is not how Xcode is designed to be used.